# Using Rail's Model.update method without providing IDs in the hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I understand that you can update some models using `Model.update(ids, values)` where `ids` represent the ID and `values` represent the actual changes. I do also understand that you can pass in a hash, such as `{1 => {column_name: "new value"}, 2 => {column_name: "new value"}}` which works just fine.

However, what if, instead of IDs, I wanted to use another column such as `uuid`? Can I use the `.update` method in such a way to where it would do something like `Model.update(uuid: hash.keys, hash.values)`?

It doesn't appear that I can do this with this method, but is there another way that I can do this so that I don't have to iterate through every single key and value in my long array (which contains thousands of keys and values)

This is what happens when I try to implement what I would like to do:

```
[2] pry(#<MyWorker>)> test = {"b7d720f984abeda37836d07b2147560ce06fb4d7e30fe8d59c1fe610cb440bbf" => {:protocol => "udp", :port => 5}}
=> {"b7d720f984abeda37836d07b2147560ce06fb4d7e30fe8d59c1fe610cb440bbf"=>{:protocol=>"udp", :port=>5}}
[3] pry(#<MyWorker>)> Port.update(uuid: test.keys, test.values)
SyntaxError: unexpected ')', expecting =>
...e(uuid: test.keys, test.values)
...                              ^
[3] pry(#<MyWorker>)>
```

Comment: What about `Port.where(...).update(...)`?

Comment: Thanks @SebastianPalma. This did the trick.

Comment: Just checking, but afaik the `where(..).update(...)` can only set all selected items to the same values. Not entirely sure if that is ok for you? Your example seems to suggest values could be different (the hash datastructure would allow that), while they are the same. There is obviously no way to know with a `update` receiving an array which selected item should get which values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sebastian Palma said, you can do this using a `where` clause before the `update` action like so:

```rb
Port.where(uuid: test.keys).update(test.values)
```